# Convert a string containing integers into an integer

Tags: python, regex, string, integer

I am trying to convert the integers contained into a string like `"15m"` into an `integer`.

With the code below I can achieve what I want. But I am wondering if there is a better solution for this, or a function I'm not aware of which already implements this.

```
s = "15m"
s_result = ""
for char in s:
    try:
        i = int(char)
        s_result = s_result + char
    except:
        pass
result = int(s_result)
print result
```

This code would output below result:

```
>>> 
15
```

Maybe there is no such "better" solution but I would like to see other solutions, like using `regex` maybe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a good solution using regex.

```
import re
result = int(re.sub('[^0-9]','', s))
print result
```

Which results in:

```
>>> 
15
```

Comment: Good answer! The result will still be a string here, so you might want to convert to an integer

Comment: you can also use `\d` instead. `int(re.sub('[^\d]','', s))`

Answer (score 1):

You could also match one or more digits from the start of the line `^\d+`

```
import re
regex = r"^\d+"
test_str = "15m"
match = re.search(regex, test_str)

if match:
    print (int(match.group()))
```